# What is the best solution for allowing an edit of individual activities in a calendar pop-up window?

Tags: interaction-design, web-app

What is the best solution for allowing an edit of individual activities in a calendar pop-up window?

We tried listing the activity code as a link for each activity, but that has visual problems with the redundancy of that link and it still might not solve the problem for how to answer the question "How do I edit one of these activities."

We thought about putting a little edit button on each line, but that also has the visual  problem of redundancy.  However, it very clearly solves the discoverable issue of answering the question "How do I edit one of these activities."

We also tried using the link on the case number to navigate to the edit of the activity.  This solves the visual issue because we are using something we have to display anyway.  However, it still might not solve the problem for how to answer the question "How do I edit one of these activities."  Also, if we use the case number link to edit an activity we introduce inconsistent behavior with a companion application where the case number link navigates to a case summary page.

[image: Calendar Pop-up]

Comment: That content looks very real. It's either really convincing dummy data, or it is real and you might want to change it as to not get into any trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I must say that this layout looks very cluttered and that is why you have a problem of pointing to the edit icon/label.

First of all it looks like you have 3 links in every line so it is not clear what link is leading where.

Second, this looks like an pop-up window ... what would be the action when you click on Edit? If you make it more clear (separate chunks of data) and give it some space you can put edit icon and it will not look redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I think putting an edit button (or simple "edit" text link) on each line, isn't too bad. This is a typical pattern for editing items from a list.

Answer (score 0):

The other common pattern is putting the edit icon, which is usually a pencil-looking icon, at the upper corner at the end of the line and is only visible when the mouse cursor is hovering the row